# Flex 4 error labelWidth

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash-builder

Im getting a error in my application with the labelWidth the question is simple i think, but i cant find the right answer.
code:

```
<s:FormItem labelWidth="0">
```

Error:
**Cannot resolve attribute 'labelWidth' for component type spark.components.FormItem.**

I´m migrating from flex 3 to 4 and a lot of things changed in application design
How can i use the labelWidth in spark?

Comment: There is no `labelWidth`. If you want to set an explicit label width, I think you'll have to create a custom skin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a syntax error. Try this:

```
<s:FormItem width="0" label="Form Item:">
      <s:Label text="label text" />
</s:FormItem>
```